# Convert to Excel with Django

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to convert some Django model to a Excel file. My view is as follows:

```
@login_required
def archive_to_excel(request):
    calculations_list = Calculations.objects.filter(user=request.user) \
                                            .values_list('make', 'model', 'first_registration', 'body', 'facelift',
                                                         'engine', 'transmission', 'purchase_price', 'mileage',
                                                         'customer__firstname', 'customer__lastname', 'customer__email') \
                                            .order_by('-id')

    columns = [_('Make'), _('Model'), _('First registration'), _('Body'), _('Facelift'), _('Engine'), _('Transmission'),
               _('Price'), _('Mileage'), _('Customer first name'), _('Customer last name'), _('Customer email')]

    return convert_to_excel("archive", columns, calculations_list)
```

And `convert_to_excel` function is as follows:

```
def convert_to_excel(file_name, columns, values):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.xls"'.format(file_name)

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet(file_name.capitalize())

    # Sheet header, first row
    row_num = 0

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

    # Sheet body, remaining rows
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()

    for row in values:
        row_num += 1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)

    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

That works fine, but the problem that I have is that the `purchase_price` in `Calculations` model is stored **EXCL VAT** and I want to show it in the excel file **INCL VAT**.

How can I multiply the `purchase_price` with 1.21 and show it in the excel file?

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for instance do this:

```
calculations_list = Calculations.objects.filter(user=request.user) \
                    .values_list('make', 'model', 'first_registration', 'body', 'facelift',
                                'engine', 'transmission', 'mileage',
                                'customer__firstname', 'customer__lastname', 'customer__email') \
                    .annotate(purchase_price=F('purchase_price')*1.21)
                    .order_by('-id')
```